# iOS 7/iPad Safari not responding to javascript confirm dialog event

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, dialog, confirm

Summary:
When "OK" button is clicked on a javascript confirm dialog, it does not execute the code in its section.

Steps to Reproduce:

```
window.location = 'myApp://openMyAppUrl' ;

timeoutIpad = setTimeout( function(){
                    var timeoutFired = new Date();

                var timeElapsed = timeoutFired.getTime() - start.getTime();

                if( timeElapsed < 3000){
                    if( confirm("You need app to continue.")){
                        if(timeElapsed < 10000){
                            var x = 1+1;
                            window.location="http://google.com/getMyApp";
                        }
                    }
                }
        }, 200);
//Timeout values of 200, 500, 1500 were attempted but same results
```

To reproduce:

1) Use the above js code on a webpage.
2) Click the first "OK" and then click the "OK" that comes from the confirm dialog.

Expected Results:
A redirection to http://google.com/getMyApp should happen in 10 seconds if the app does not exist.

Actual Results:
The sub routine for the true condition for the confirm() dialog does not get executed. The following is seen on xcode console:

Nov  5 09:24:06 Tests-iPad MobileSafari[327] : *** Assertion failure in -UIApplication runModal:, /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UIApplication.m:9465
Nov  5 09:24:06 Tests-iPad MobileSafari[327] : *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate:  The view passed in does not have a window.

Version:
**7.0.0-7.0.3**
I saw reports that issue was fixed in 7.0.3 but I don't see it.